# Adding loading function to objective c tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently I have a table that is updated by a server query, so it is not instant. Currently I populate the array in the `viewDidLoad` delegate method like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    followers = [[User sharedManager] loadFollowers];    
}
```

However, what happens is that I press the button to modal transition into the tableview and it then waits for the query to succeed and only then pulls up the view. Obviously this is really annoying since it feels like it's crashing/lagging. I'd rather it pulls up the page instantly and has a "loading..." or an activity view while the query executes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following(it will not look like lagging or crashing):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(load_followers)];

-(void)load_followers
{
    followers = [[User sharedManager] loadFollowers]; 
}
```

You always have to do such queries in a background thread. you don't want the interface to freeze and preventing the user to interact with the application.

Comment: Great thanks! Any opinions on using this in viewDidLoad vs viewDidAppear? @hasan

Comment: viewdidload cause you want that to finish  asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of networking stuff you should look at classes like `NSURLConnection` or libraries like `AFNetworking` that make networking trivial.

You need to ensure that the networking stuff is not run on the main (UI) thread. You can do this with gcd like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  self.followers = [[User sharedManager] loadFollowers];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // update the UI now new data has been stored
    // e.g. [self reloadData];
  });
});
```